# How to add a UIButton to GLKit View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uibutton, glkit

I need to add a **UIButton** on a **GLKit** view. I am trying the same on the default openGL program that is created by Xcode.

Can some one help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out myself. Posting detail just incase someone else is looking at the same problem.

To add a button to your GLKView, add the following code snippet in your ViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //Initialise GLKView. Set Context, depth format etc.

  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
  [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [button setEnabled:YES];

  [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)onClick:(id)sender
{
  //Do onClick stuff here
  [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

-
Hochester